# Unable to load KEXT on macOS 10.13.6 & later

Tags: xcode, driver, macos-high-sierra, macos-mojave, kernel-extension

We are facing issues while loading kernel extensions on macOS 10.13.6 and later (macOS 10.14.6 beta as well).
We have KAUTH kext, we copy it to  **"/Library/Extensions/"** and call **KextManagerLoadKextWithURL()** API.

In System Preferences we click on Allow button for loading the KEXT.

After performing these actions KEXT does not get loaded. So we analysed more and found below observations.

> 1) KEXT entry present in **"/Library/Extensions"** &
>   **"/Library/StagedExtensions/"**
>
> 2) We read **/private/var/db/SystemPolicyConfiguration/KextPolicy**.
>   KextPolicy database contains:
>   **XXXXXXXXXX|com.company.driver.kauthkext|1|Company (P) Ltd.|5** From point 2 we have conclusive evidence that KEXT is allowed to load.

So we analysed more and found below difference. Here **System1** able to load kext and **System2** unable to load kext.

**System1**: (Upgraded from lower OS to higher OS)

```
System1:~ user$ ls -laO /Library/StagedExtensions/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x@  3 root  wheel  restricted   96 Jun 27 15:15 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 62 root  wheel  sunlnk     1984 Jul  3 12:24 ..
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel  restricted  128 Jul  4 16:15 Library
```

**System2**: (Fresh hardware having 10.13.6 OS preinstalled)

```
System2:~ user $ ls -laO /Library/StagedExtensions/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x@  3 root  wheel  -   96 Jun 27 15:15 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 62 root  wheel  sunlnk     1984 Jul  3 12:24 ..
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel  -  128 Jul  4 16:15 Library
```

Somehow **"restricted"** flag is playing role to manipulate KEXT loading.

> Note: We have not added any flags to the
>   **"/Library/StagedExtensions"** directory. SIP (System Integrity Protection) is enabled on both machines

Please guide us why KEXT does not get load on System2.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the output of the `kextutil /Library/Extensions/YourKext.kext` command?

Comment: @pmdj: Thanks for response. Following is the output:

Kext rejected due to insecure location: <OSKext 0x5g4e556wse20 [0x5g4e556wse20]> { URL = "file:///Library/StagedExtensions/Library/Extensions/mykauth.kext/", ID = "com.company.driver.kauthkext" }

Comment: I don't know why your `StagedExtensions` directory does not have the "restricted" flag set. It should, and it looks like that might be the cause for your problem. The best I can think of is to boot in recovery mode, and run "First Aid" on the volume in Disk Utility there. Alternatively, you could try to delete StagedExtensions altogether and hope the OS recreates it with the correct flags. But that might make things worse if it doesn't.

Comment: In the development environment it is totally possible but in the customer environment having thousands it was near to impossible as we can not guarantee of successful execution.. Need to find some way out to resolve problem..

Comment: If this really is a fresh macOS install with StagedExtensions excluded from SIP, it sounds like a bug in the installer, and you'll need to raise it with Apple - Radar and DTS. I don't think you can add the flag (`sudo chflags restricted`) except in the recovery environment or with SIP disabled, so this probably isn't an option on live systems.

Comment: @pmdj : If this so, I will definitely raise the issue at Apple - Radar and DTS. Thanks for your time. Apart from this if there is any other lead, then would like to here it. Thank you once again

Comment: @pmdj: raised bug on Apple developer support, will update once we get any reply